# How do I install pod on M1

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently getting this issue when installing podfile. I've been trying to install pod install, but It keeps failing. The error message is below.

> You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
> Bug reports are welcome.
> For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
> [IMPORTANT]
> Don't forget to include the Crash Report log file under
> DiagnosticReports directory in bug reports.
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCoWj.png)

Comment: Ok, stop. You are using the wrong Ruby. You need to back off and start over by installing your own ruby (I like to use homebrew and rbenv for this). Rule 1: if you have to say sudo, you're doing it wrong. You're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If using M1 and don't want to enter `arch -x86-64` everytime, you can use this command to install `ffi` instead:

```
gem install --user-install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc
```

And then it should be able to run `pod install` without it. Using `sudo` might be needed.

[Reference](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/864)

Comment: If use of sudo is needed, this is the wrong Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Open applications folder and find Terminal in Utilities folder and right click on it and select get info and check **Open Using Rosetta**

[image]

Then follow the regular [intel cocoapod installation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) it will work.

Answer (score -1):

M1 is compatible to arm, so when performing arch related commands, it is operated under arm64. so an architecture will be set to x86_64 to install ffi.

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

M1 should indicates x86_64 when installing pod on M1 Macbook, cause to be synchronize on an architecture.

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: No. Use of sudo shows this is the wrong Ruby.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

follow steps

1. remove the pod

   $ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

   $ pod deintegrate

   $ pod cache clean --all

   $ rm Podfile

2.Install pod

Right-click on Terminal in Finder
Get Info
Open with Rosetta
I installed a gem that seems to be related to the symbol not found in the
error:

```
sudo gem install ffi
```

Comment: Nope. The need to say sudo is a Bad Smell.